Antd message not showing in built environment
I am developing a React-Vite web application using typescript and antd. I tried to replace my alert with antd's message.warning() function. However, I encountered problem that while it works on my dev environment, the message is not showing up in the vite build dist. There is an error message displayed whenever the message is supposed to show up: window.getRootPrefixCls is not a function which I supposed I have to perform some vite config setup for my build to recognise global functions registered by antd. I tried to look it up but couldn't figure out how to manage that.
Followings are my relevant dependencies:
    "react": "^18.3.0-next-1a08f1478-20221103",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.0-next-1a08f1478-20221103",
    "antd": "^5.11.1",

